# Cannot send variable name from one node module to another to use it as a room-name for chat application using socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, socket.io, backend

I am able to get the room name from user but as I use `module.exports` in another file to retrieve it shows undefined . This might be because it is asynchronous.

//roomcheck.js

```
var nsp = io.of("/gameroom");
nsp.on('connection', (socket) => {
socket.on('check', (data) => {
    if (rm.includes(data)) {
        roomname = data;
        console.log(roomname);
        console.log("Room exist!!!");
        socket.emit('success', 'room already made');
});

module.exports=roomname;
```

//userpage.js

```
var r=require('roomcheck.js');
console.log(r.roomname);
```

**Expected** - roomname entered by user.

**My output** - undefined

Comment: What should happen if multiple users connect? Should the name be logged multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

- Firstly, you are right, it is becouse it is asynchronous
- Secondly you have set the module.exports itself to be the roomname, which means that module.exports is not an object it is the string  itself

So basically r is module.exports

If I were you I would make module.exports and object that has an onRoomCheck function to which I could pass a callback to

Example code:

//roomcheck.js

```
var roomCheckCallback = ()=>{};
var nsp = io.of("/gameroom");
nsp.on('connection', (socket) => {
socket.on('check', (data) => {
    if (rm.includes(data)) {
        roomname = data;
        console.log(roomname);
        roomCheckCallback({roomname:roomname,exists:true});
        console.log("Room exist!!!");
        socket.emit('success', 'room already made');
    } else { roomCheckCallback({roomname:null,exists:false}); }
});
module.exports = {}
module.exports.onRoomCheck = function(callback){
    roomCheckCallBack = callback;
}
```

//userpage.js

```
var r=require('roomcheck.js');
r.onRoomCheck( (room)=> { console.log(room.roomname) } );
```

Comment: It's not working , the console.log(room.roomname) shows no output.
i want only the string value of roomname so that i can use socket.to(<roomname>).emit() to emit within a particular room

Comment: Is there no output, or is the output undefined? If there is no output that means the callback never gets called in roomcheck.js

Comment: //userpage.js
var r = require('./roomcheck');
     r.onRoomCheck((room) => {
    console.log(":__" + room.roomname);
    });

NO OUTPUT of console.log in userpage.js

Comment: Add a cosole.log into socket.on("check") to see if that runs

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is to make a delay by setTimeout function 
In roomcheck.js

```
setTimeout(()=>{
module.exports=roomname;
},1000);
```

This provides a delay of 1 second and gives roomcheck.js to get the roomname and then export it